# R: Clustering results are different everytime I run

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, weka, k-means

```
library(amap)
set.seed(5)
Kmeans(mydata, 5, iter.max=500, nstart=1, method="euclidean")
```

in 'amap' package and run several times, but even though the parameters and seed value are always the same, the clustering results are different every time I run Kmeans, or other cluster methods.

I tried another kmeans function in different packages, but still the same...

In fact, I want to use the Weka and R together, so I also tried `SimpleKMeans` in RWeka package, and this gives always the same value. However, the problem is that I do not know how to store the clustered data along with the cluster number from SimpleKmeans in RWeka so I'm stuck...

Anyhow, how can I keep the clustering result always the same? or How can I store the clustering result from `SimpleKmeans` into R?

Comment: are you resetting the seed each time you run `Kmeans`, or just the first time? If you reset the seed each time, you should get the same answer every time.

Answer (score 10):

You must be doing something wrong. I get reproducible results each time I run the following code, as long as I set the seed before each call to `Kmeans()`:

```
library(amap)

out <- vector(mode = "list", length = 10)
for(i in seq_along(out)) {
    set.seed(1)
    out[[i]] <- Kmeans(iris[, -5], 3, iter.max=500, nstart=1, method="euclidean")
}

for(i in seq_along(out[-1])) {
    print(all.equal(out[[i]], out[[i+1]]))
}
```

The last for loop prints:

```
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
```

Indicating the results are exactly the same each time.

Comment: Edited code example to include `library(amap)` and function `Kmeans`

Comment: +1 For showing how set.seed should be used each time that Kmeans is called.

Comment: @Andrie thanks for the edit updating this to `Kmeans()` now the OP tells us where this is found.

Answer (score 5):

Just a reminder that K-mean results are sensitive to the order of the data points in the data set. If you run again the proper code with randomized data points you will get a different result

Answer (score 3):

Have you set the seed?
`set.seed(1)`

Everytime K-Means initializes the centroid, it is generated randomly, which is needing seed for generating random values.