# R kmeans (stats) vs Kmeans (amap)

Tags: r, k-means

Hello stackoverflow community,

I'm running **kmeans** (stats package) and **Kmeans** (amap package) on the Iris dataset. In both cases, I use the same algorithm (Lloyd–Forgy), the same distance (euclidean), the same number of initial random sets (50), the same maximal number of iterations (1000), and I test for the same set of k values (from 2 to 15). I also use the same seed for both cases (4358).

I don't understand why under these conditions I'm getting different wss curves, in particular: the "elbow" using the stats package is much less accentuated than when using the amap package.

Could you please help me to understand why? Thanks much!

Here the code:

```
# data load and scaling
newiris <- iris
newiris$Species <- NULL
newiris <- scale(newiris)

# using kmeans (stats)
wss1 <- (nrow(newiris)-1)*sum(apply(newiris,2,var))
for (i in 2:15) {
  set.seed(4358)
  wss1[i] <- sum(kmeans(newiris, centers=i, iter.max=1000, nstart=50,
                       algorithm="Lloyd")$withinss)
  }

# using Kmeans (amap)
library(amap)
wss2 <- (nrow(newiris)-1)*sum(apply(newiris,2,var))
for (i in 2:15) {
  set.seed(4358)
  wss2[i] <- sum(Kmeans(newiris, centers=i, iter.max=1000, nstart=50,
                       method="euclidean")$withinss)
  }

# plots
plot(1:15, wss1, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters",
     ylab="Within groups sum of squares", main="kmeans (stats package)")
plot(1:15, wss2, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters",
     ylab="Within groups sum of squares", main="Kmeans (amap package)")
```

**EDIT:**
*I've emailed the author of the amap package and will post the reply when/if I get any.*
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/amap/index.html

Comment: if you want to dig further, you can read the source code for each function by typing just the function name and hitting enter

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696381/r-clustering-results-are-different-everytime-i-run

Comment: Thanks for your comments @pcantalupo. I'm reading the code and try to understand it. For the possible duplicate: thanks for the pointer. I am using the seed as suggested in that post. The difference I notice is not between different runs of the same function, but between the two different implementations (stats vs. map packages). Side comment: when I run Kmeans (amap) with and without `set.seed(4358)` I get the same was graph, which I think is weird

Comment: Is that after you have set the seed once?

Comment: Yes @Elin, I set the seed once in each for loop: once before kmeans (stats) and once before Kmeans (amap), the same in both instances (`set.seed(4358)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the amap package, changed the code and the value of withinss variable is the sum applied by method (eg. euclidean distance).

One way to solve this, given the return of Kmeans function (amap), recalculate the value of withinss ( Error Sum of Squares (SSE) ).

Here is my suggestion:

**# using Kmeans (amap)**

```
    library(amap)

    wss2 <- (nrow(newiris)-1)*sum(apply(newiris,2,var))

    for (i in 2:15) {

            set.seed(4358)

            ans.Kmeans <- Kmeans(newiris, centers=i, iter.max=1000, nstart=50, method="euclidean")

            wss <- vector(mode = "numeric", length=i) 

            for (j in 1:i) {
                    km = as.matrix(newiris[which(ans.Kmeans$cluster %in% j),])

                    ## average = as.matrix( t(apply(km,2,mean) )) 
                    ## wss[j] =  sum( apply(km, 1, function(x) sum((x-average) ^ 2 )))
                    ## or                         
                    wss[j] <- ( nrow(km)-1) * sum(apply(km,2,var))
            }

            wss2[i] = sum(wss)
    }
```

Note. The method for pearson in this package is wrong (be careful !) on version 0.8-14.

Line 325 according code in this link:

https://github.com/cran/amap/blob/master/src/distance_T.inl